# Local and global solutions for $y′= 6x^2\sqrt y $

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> Solve the differential equation $$y′= 6x^2\sqrt y $$ and draw the phase portrait.  Find out how many solutions with initial conditions $(x_0,y_0) = (a,b)$ this equations possesses depending on $(a,b)$.  Consider both cases:  local and global solutions.

I have solved the differential equation and got $y = (x^3-c)^2$, but i dont know how to do the rest of the question. Also is it importent to let it be $-c$ instead of $+c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the site indicated at the top of this image which will give you a graphical representation at a certain scale of the field of "speed vectors" with coordiantes $(x,y')$ but also an idea of any solution if you provide initial data.

Do you see how well the solution curve I have asked follows the vector field ?

It is indeed necessary to assume $c<0$.

[image]

Comment: The interesting feature here is to realize that the solution is not always unique. Taking the solution you depicted, if satisfies $y(-1)=0$. However, if you solve the IVP with this last condition condition, you get two solutions: $y=0$ and "yours".